# Excel formula compare two strings

Tags: string, vba, excel, text

[image: screen shot of formula click here]

I need to compare a product from a transaction file to a product in a lookup worksheet.  The values appear to be equal but do not evaluate as equal.  Been trying different approaches in VBA (StrComp, CStr, Trim(), adding a letter to the beginning and end of the strings for comparison) and Excel formulas to try and solve this.

In the photo, 
Cell C4 was copied from the transaction work book, and cell D4 was copied from the lookup workbook.  The formula evaluates to False.  If I just type this string value into two different cells and apply the formula, it evaluates to True, but when I copy the two cells from other workbooks (a transaction worksheet, and a lookup worksheet), the formula evaluates to false.

Any ideas?

Excel Formula:  `=IF(TRIM(UPPER(C4))=TRIM(UPPER(D4)),TRUE, FALSE)`

A5314A  A5314A

Comment: If you copy the Celle and paste AS values,is it true or false? Can it be that there are not visible signs within the Celle?

Comment: Max, it still evaluates as False when I paste values.

Comment: Can you copy paste the cell values into the question?

Comment: There will be some hidden / not visible so signs. I can post code to eliminate Thema tomorrow.

Comment: Assume you tested start of strings with Code() worksheet function ?

Comment: Maybe try `EXACT(TRIM(UPPER(C4)), TRIM(UPPER(D4)))`?

Comment: I copied and pasted all of your data and it's working for me. Try recreating this in a blank new Excel project

Comment: Somewhere on your sheet, enter `=LEN(C4)` and `=LEN(D4)`. There may be hidden characters in the cells

Comment: QHarr, the values are pasted in the bottom of the post.  No, I am not familiar with Code()... I will investigate.   When I was copying the cell values in the post, I copied and pasted them back to Excel from the editor and the formula evaluated False.... when I saved the edit and then again copied from the saved edited post, the formula evaluates to true.

Comment: Code Different, that's it... the first cell is 9 and the second is 6.  Must be something hidden like QHarr referenced above.

Comment: Ioannis - this evaluates False

Comment: Try adding `Clean` to you function .  `TRIM(UPPER(CLEAN(C4)))`

Comment: chris neilsen, thanks yes that worked!  The excel formula evaluated to true.  Do you know if there is a VBA equivalent method?

Comment: WorksheetFunction.Clean()

Answer (score 0):

In Excel using the CLEAN function like Chris Neilsen suggested was the answer:

`=IF(TRIM(UPPER(CLEAN(C4)))=TRIM(UPPER(CLEAN(D4))),TRUE, FALSE)`

As Sam suggested in VBA using this function also worked and the StrComp method evaluated to 0:

```
a = "A" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(CStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value2))) & "A"`
b = "A" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(CStr(Sheet2.Cells(i2, 1).Value2))) & "A"
If StrComp(a, b) = 0 Then
```